# How to formulate condition whether list contains more than one object? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following problem. I want to create an if else statement where if the condition is true you get redirected to a certain page & if it is false to another. For that I need to check whether a list has more than one object, but I don't know how to formulate the condition.

Here is the if else statement (I wrote 3>0 for the condition as a placeholder)

```
      child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: modell.modelData.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (3 > 0) {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Modelljahre(
                        modelData: this.modell.modelData[index],
                        modell: modell,
                      )));
        } else {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Treibstoff()));
        }
        ;
      },
```

and here a part of the dataset (so I want to check whether the VariantMakeData list of each car Modell contains more than one object, how can I do that?

```
    ModelMakeData(id: 27, title: "Touareg", variantenData: <VariantMakeData>[
  VariantMakeData(
    id: 1,
    bigtitle: "1. Generation",
    title: "Modelljahre 2002-2010",
  ),
  VariantMakeData(
    id: 2,
    bigtitle: "2. Generation",
    title: "Modelljahre 2010-2018",
  ),
```

Comment: `if (yourList.length > 1)` ?

Comment: if(modell.modelData.length>1)

Comment: uff just realised the stupidity of the question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
if (modell.modelData[index].variantenData.length >1)
```

Because you want to check the length of `variantenData` at this current index

Answer (score 0):

You can use the propriety isNotEmpty like this:

```
if (modell.modelData.isNotEmpty){
   //Your code
} else {
   // Your code
}
```